# JPA how to include nulls values with Order by

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, null, sql-order-by

I am trying to order by a field of a sub-entity (the "text" field from "Nature" entity which is in "Act" entity).
The "nature" entity is a field of actRoot.

here is my code:

```
 @Override
    public Order apply(Root<Act> actRoot, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
        Expression<?> nature = builder.selectCase()
                .when(builder.isNull(actRoot.get("nature")), "")
                .otherwise(actRoot.get("nature").get("text"))
                .as(String.class);
        return builder.asc(nature);
    }
```

So I create a temp table of string type, with default empty value for Acts with null "nature". The problem is that hibernate does not return the Acts where "nature" is null. There is no error at all. 
I need a result with first the Acts with non null "nature" ordered by "text" field then all Acts with null "nature"

Any suggestion ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution: 
I needed a JOIN.

```
  @Override
    public Order apply(Root<Act> actRoot, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
        Join join = actRoot.join("nature", LEFT);
        return builder.asc(join.get("text"));
    }
```